# "Practical Django Projects" - Search function

Tags: python, django

I am reading Chapter 3 of "Practical Django Projects", on how to make a CMS. I have improved the search function and everything works fine. However I am wondering why everythings works...

On page 35, I have added an admin.py file in the cms/search/ directory. How does the compiler know that he needs to take this file into account ?

On page 36-37, there is an improved version of the cms/search/models.py. It seems that the new file adds not just 1 keyword, but 3 ! How come ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "compiler"?  What do you mean by "compiler"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `admin.autodiscover()` in your `urls.py` Django's `admin.site` will be looking for `admin.py` files in all packages of your `INSTALLED_APPS` and import all found `ModelAdmin` classes and add them to the `admin.site`.

You have three inputs for `SearchKeyword` appearing in the admin because the there are three InlineAdmin's added.

Comment: Thanks. Why 3 ? All that is written is : inlines = [SearchKeywordInline].

Comment: 2 is Djano's default, but you can set another number as well via [`InlineModelAdmin.extra`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra)